# C++ auto type specifier compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Just for curiosity:

is it big difference in compile time if `auto` type specifiers  have been used?

I haven't found any information regarding that.

Comment: There is an overhead but it's very low. However there are situations where auto is just syntax sugar for a template, when using it as a function parameter for example, and obviously there the cost can start to increase. Personally I would say that I've never worked in a codebase where use of auto has been the main reason for poor compile times.

Comment: The compiler always has to determine the type of every expression, so all the information `auto` needs is already available to it. On the other hand, not using `auto` might add some overhead for determining if any conversions are necessary and possibly generating code for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the compiler is already aware of the static type of an expression, you can expect the effect on compilation time to be minimal, if any.

Probably of the same order as using `decltype` or `sizeof`.